# How to change value of a control (label) within a UserControl added multiple times inside a panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel to which I add a certain number of the same user control according to the selected item of a combo. I need to change the value of a label every time the user enters a value within a textbox. This is for each UC added to the panel:

[image: Image Sample]

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Handling the `onTextBoxChanged` event can help you maybe,

Comment: Hi.. To use "onTextBoxChanged" I'll have to enable AutoPostBack="True" and the page will postback every time the user enters a value on every textbox. 
I've tried this way and for some reason it only updates the first label of the first user control..

Comment: I forgot to mention that the UC are addded programatically

Comment: @christianvalera You also forgot to mention that this is on a web page.

Comment: Yes, you are right... Thank you for the clarification. Indeed is on a web page